# Vi editor pattern matching

Tags: regex, linux, unix, vi

Suppose the data is in following format in a log file.

```
    *******************************************
      Refreshing token for  app foo1
    *******************************************
      Refreshing token for  app foo2
    *******************************************
      Refreshing token for  app foo3
      Update application with name: foo3
      Done
      Waiting 1 second
    *******************************************
```

This data says that refresh token for foo1 and foo2 is incomplete and refresh token token for foo3 is complete.

I need to separate the apps for which refresh tokens didn't complete.

How to match foo1 and foo2 using vi editor.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check it out: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines

Comment: http://www.lagmonster.org/docs/vi2.html This will benefit you as well

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Looks like based on the sample data, you need to search for number at the end of the line, where the first character on the following line is a splat.

Comment: What exact flavors of unix and vi are you using?  Will you use vim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using vim, with the file open:

```
<Esc>       To go to command mode
:1 <Enter>  to go to line 1
/           Start a search
\d          a digit
\n          followed by a newline
\*          followed by an escaped splat
<Enter>     You will be positioned at the first match
n           go to the next match
```

It will look like this at the bottom left:

```
/\d\n\*
```

Of course the digit matches your test data, but you'll have to tweak it to match your real data.

Answer (score 0):

This is also working

```
 :set hlsearch
    /\*\{30,}\n\s\+Refreshing\stoken\sapp\s\a\a\a\d\n\*\{30,}
```

- :set hlsearch highlights the search results
- *{30,} Matches the line containing special character * occurring more than 30 times
- \n Matches new line
- \s\+ Matches white space more than once
- \a Matches a character
- \d Matches a number